# Can i use -Format Operator in Write-Host or Write-Debug?

Tags: powershell, format

Do i miss something or is it not possible to get my formatting in a Write-Debug statement?

```
"Date: {0:d}" -f (Get-Date) #Works as expected

Write-Debug "Date: {0:d}" -f (Get-Date) #Does not work
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing $DebugPreference to "continue" and add some parens:

**$DebugPreference = "Continue"**

**Write-Debug ("Date: {0:d}" -f (Get-Date))**

The default for $DebugPreference is "SilentlyContinue" so Write-Debug won't display anything.

Write-Host will just work if you enclose your message in the parens.

Comment: Thank You, I was aware of the DebugPreference  but missing the ()